# Interrupt in C++

Tags: c++, linux, interrupt

I am trying to understand interrupts and am looking for a simple code that uses interrupts. Could somebody please help me with it?

Comment: Isn't that the operating system's job?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=interrupts+C%2B%2B, there are loads of good examples there.  Is there anything specific you're trying to understand?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples using the alarm function. alarm causes SIGALRM to happen n seconds after you call that function.

This program will run for 3 seconds, and then die with SIGALRM.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    alarm(3);
    while(true);
}
```

In this case, we'd like to catch SIGALRM, and die gracefully with a message:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

volatile bool alarmed = false;

void alrm_handler(int) {
    alarmed = true;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGALRM, alrm_handler);

    alarm(3);
    while(not alarmed);

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use ualarm instead of alarm now but it doesn't seem to be working. :( The code looks like: #include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

volatile bool alarmed = false;

void alrm_handler(int) {
    alarmed = true;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGALRM, alrm_handler);

    ualarm(3000000, 0);
    while(not alarmed);

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}

Comment: From the man page of ualarm, the first argument must be less than 1000000. See: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ualarm.3.html